# Add information when printing an invoice [Odoo 15]

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I want to add more information in the printing of an invoice. I tried inheriting report_invoice.xml and account_invoice_report.py, and I added both on **manifest**.py

It still doesn't work (New info is not showing on the print) and I want to know why. Can u guys help me? Here is the code

**report_invoice.xml**

```
 <odoo>
        <data>
            <template inherit_id="report_invoice_document">
                <div id="informations" class="row mt-4 mb-4">
                    <div class="col-auto col-3 mw-100 mb-2" t-if="o.invoice_date" name="invoice_date">
                        <strong>Invoice Date:</strong>
                        <p class="m-0" t-field="o.invoice_date"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </template>
        </data>
</odoo>
```

**account_invoice_report.py**

```
class AccountInvoiceReport(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.invoice.report"
```

Comment: The second one "account.invoice.report" has nothing to do with the printable pdf. That's the model for the invoice statistics report.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Which is the model related to the printable PDF?

Comment: What you're looking for on your second part is described [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/reports.html#custom-reports). But for your extension it's not needed. It's usually used to introduce either special data or special functionality, which then can be used in the QWeb report.

Comment: Oh that link provided in my comment is for Odoo 15! In way older versions there is no `_get_report_values()`. But there was another method for the same purpose. IIRC overriding `render_html` was one way to do it. But as i said before, i think you don't need it for this extension.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the template id and when Odoo will try to compute the [full template id](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/tools/convert.py#L592-L594) it will raise the following error (in the log):

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

To fix that error just set the template id.

To add some information to the invoice report you just need to inherit the invoice report document and make the module depend on the `account` module

You can check the OCA [account_tax_invoice_note](https://github.com/OCA/account-invoicing/blob/15.0/account_invoice_tax_note/reports/report_invoice_document.xml#L5) module which inherited the invoice report to add tax information